# How do i start a program from cmd window when right click pasting to it or after a time?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a small batch file which i use to download videos in various formats
i usually just double click the icon & it pops up a cmd window, where i have to right click & paste the link, then hit enter to start it

what i would like to do is either have it auto start when the link is pasted to the cmd window, or have a timer, say 5 seconds, where it will auto start after 5 seconds (link pasted or not)

i saw info about the timeout command, but i'm not sure if that will auto start after the link is pasted, also saw one (startkeys?) but saw it said it needs window focus to work (i usually paste & go back to the browser so i assume it would 'enter' on the browser)

this is my batch file. im not sure if it's possible to do what i want, or where exactly i'd put the command

thanks for any help (my first post here)

```
set /p input="1080p Input URL: "

@echo 1080

yt -f 137+140 "%input%"

@if %errorlevel%=="ERROR: requested format not available" GOTO Label2
@if %errorlevel%==0 GOTO Label6


:Label2
@echo 720
yt -f 136+140 "%input%"

@if %errorlevel%=="ERROR: requested format not available" GOTO Label3
@if %errorlevel%==0 GOTO Label6


:Label3
@echo 480
yt -f 135+140 "%input%"

@if %errorlevel%=="ERROR: requested format not available" GOTO Label4
@if %errorlevel%==0 GOTO Label6


:Label4
@echo 360
yt -f 18+140 "%input%"

@if %errorlevel%=="ERROR: requested format not available" GOTO Label5
@if %errorlevel%==0 GOTO Label6


:Label5
@echo 240
yt -f 133+140 "%input%"


:Label6
pause
```

Comment: I'm not convinced that your current code is okay, so adding to it would not be a wise idea at this time. (Not that this site provides a coding service anyway). An `%errorlevel%` has for me, always been numeric, not a string.

Comment: it seems to work ok. 
the errorlevel line i copied from another post here ages ago, it worked so i just assumed it was ok

Comment: It works more by luck than anything else, as the `@if %errorlevel%=="ERROR: requested format not available"` will never be true, first because that will never be output as an error level and secondly because an unquoted string will never match a quoted one. So all that happens is your `@if %errorlevel%==0 GOTO Label#` is checked, if it fails the code just runs the next line which is your `:label#` anyhow. Simply removing all of those `@if %errorlevel%=="ERROR: requested format not available" GOTO Label#` lines will run your code in exactly the same way.

Comment: so i only needed the label?
i removed all the lines you said but now it repeats the lines after (like it tries all commands instead of skipping them)

Comment: it needs a way to skip to label 6 if any of the previous were successful
also, thanks for your help compo

Comment: Why not just forget about all of those checks and just download the `best` version? `youtube-dl.exe -f best "URL"`

Comment: Also, I'm not sure why you'd want to run a command to download a video from a website if no URL was provided! _You said "auto start after 5 seconds (link pasted or not)"_ For me, it would make more sense to close after five seconds if no URL was provided, or provide a default fixed URL if none was provided within the time allowed.

Comment: oh, i was just thinking of the time it would take to change window & paste the link to it.
that sounds like a better way to do it, but i also dont want the 4k version if there is one (unless i do want it, which can happen)
thanks again for your help compo

Answer (score 0):

The batch file script can get whatever is on the clipboard programmatically. If you are on a supported Windows system, PowerShell will be available.

```
FOR /F %%A IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command "Get-Clipboard -Raw"') DO (SET "input=%%~A")
ECHO input is set to %input%
```

If you have a .jpeg file of your dog on the clipboard, this is unlikely to work.

You do still need to address @Compo's suggestions. %ERRORLEVEL% is numeric, not a string.

Comment: i have a program that grabs links from the clipboard, but the problem is it grabs every link
.
i tried your code, but it just says invalid retry count